# Create a treeview array of object in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to create a treeview array for use in Angular UI Tree. I want to create the structure from a array of object like this:

0: Object 
body: null
categoryDescription: null
categoryTopic: null
description: null
faqBodyId: 0
faqCategoryId: 0
faqGroupId: 1
groupDescription: null
groupName: "Generelt"
groupTopic: "Generelt"
themeCode: "GEN"
topic: null

1: Object body: null categoryDescription: "Test af kategori" categoryTopic: "Mail" description: null faqBodyId: 0 faqCategoryId: 2 faqGroupId: 1 groupDescription: null groupName: null groupTopic: null themeCode: null topic: null

2: Object body: "This is a test" categoryDescription: null categoryTopic: null description: "Testing" faqBodyId: 3 faqCategoryId: 2 faqGroupId: 0 groupDescription: null groupName: null groupTopic: null themeCode: null topic: "Test123"

etc...

It is in three levels. Group, Category and Body
A node does not allways have a child!

I want It in this structure and three levels:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "1. dragon-breath",
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "2. moiré-vision",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 21,
        "title": "2.1. tofu-animation",
        "items": [
          {
            "id": 211,
            "title": "2.1.1. spooky-giraffe",
            "items": []
          },
          {
            "id": 212,
            "title": "2.1.2. bubble-burst",
            "items": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "title": "2.2. barehand-atomsplitting",
        "items": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "3. unicorn-zapper",
    "items": []
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "4. romantic-transclusion",
    "items": []
  }
]
```

[Structure](http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/)

How is that done with Angular code?

Comment: those look like standard JavaScript JSON Arrays to me, but your example data needs to be formatted here, it's hard to understand what that's supposed to represent.

Comment: It is JSON format.. Sorry that I didn't mention that. The editor here pulls it all together.. Is there a trick for that?

Comment: according to the documentation you linked, the Angular JS UI Tree supports JSON data natively.  Did you try your data and have some unexpected result?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this. 
The input array is sorted:

```
 function buildtree(arr) {
        var group = [];

        angular.forEach(arr, function (value, index) {
            if (value.faqGroupId > 0 && value.faqCategoryId == 0 && value.faqBodyId == 0) {
                var category = [];
                var faqgroup = {
                    "id": value.faqGroupId,
                    "title": value.groupTopic,
                    "description": value.groupDescription,
                    "name": value.groupName,
                    "items": category
                }
                angular.forEach(arr, function (valuecat, index) {
                    if (value.faqGroupId == valuecat.faqGroupId && valuecat.faqCategoryId > 0 && valuecat.faqBodyId == 0) {
                        var body = [];
                        var faqcat = {
                            "id": valuecat.faqCategoryId,
                            "title": valuecat.categoryTopic,
                            "description": valuecat.categoryDescription,
                            "items": body
                        }
                        angular.forEach(arr, function (valuebod, index) {
                            if (valuecat.faqGroupId == valuebod.faqGroupId && valuecat.faqCategoryId == valuebod.faqCategoryId && valuebod.faqBodyId > 0) {
                                var faqbody = {
                                    "id": valuebod.faqBodyId,
                                    "title": valuebod.topic,
                                    "description": valuebod.description,
                                    "body": valuebod.body,
                                }
                                body.push(faqbody);
                            }
                        })
                        category.push(faqcat);
                    }
                })
                group.push(faqgroup);
            }
        });

        return group;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Array list :

Flat object array list

```
 var dataList= [
    {'id':1 ,'parentid' : 0, 'label'="label 1"},
    {'id':4 ,'parentid' : 2 ,'label'="label 2"},
    {'id':3 ,'parentid' : 1, 'label'="label 3"},
    {'id':5 ,'parentid' : 0, 'label'="label 4"},
    {'id':6 ,'parentid' : 0, 'label'="label 5"},
    {'id':2 ,'parentid' : 1, 'label'="label 6"},
    {'id':7 ,'parentid' : 4, 'label'="label 7"},
    {'id':8 ,'parentid' : 1, 'label'="label 8"}
  ];
```

covert flat object array list to treeview list

```
function flatListToTreeViewData(dataList) {
    var tree = [],
        mappedArr = {},
        arrElem,
        mappedElem;

    for (var i = 0, len = dataList.length; i < len; i++) {
        arrElem = dataList[i];
        mappedArr[arrElem.id] = arrElem;
        mappedArr[arrElem.id]['children'] = [];
    }

    for (var id in mappedArr) {
        if (mappedArr.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            mappedElem = mappedArr[id];

            array of children.
            if (mappedElem.parentID) {
                mappedArr[mappedElem['parentID']]['children'].push(mappedElem);
            }else {
                tree.push(mappedElem);
            }
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```